# Por que declarar explicitamente a base ao chamar função quando usando templates?

Tags: c++, template

Tenho o seguinte código: Uma derivada template chamando uma função de uma base também template.

```
template <int M>
struct Base { void foo() {} };

template <int M>
struct Derived : public Base<M> {
    void bar() { foo(); }
};
```

Mas isso causa o seguinte erro:

> `main.cpp`: In member function `void Derived<M>::bar()`:
> `main.cpp:7:22`: **error:** there are no arguments to `foo` that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of `foo` must be available [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
> void bar() { foo(); }
> ```

A correção do erro é simples, basta usar `Base<M>::foo();` no lugar da chamada de `foo()`.

Minha dúvida é: **Por que** esse erro ocorre? Por que foi imposta essa restrição de que eu devo explicitar a base manualmente e que o compilador não pode deduzir isso por conta própria? Por que só quando usando templates? O meu código é de alguma forma ambíguo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque o compilador não procura por símbolos em classes base dependentes de parâmetros de template na resolução de nomes [C++FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html).

Para fazer isso o compilador precisaria esperar até o momento que o template é instanciado para resolver os nomes, e uma vez para cada instanciação dele, o que deixaria o processo de compilação (ainda) mais lento.

Da forma como está especificado, o compilador procura por `foo` enquanto `bar` ainda é um template, e como não está explicitamente qualificado ele não olha na classe base. Mesmo que no caso geral ela tenho o `foo`, você poderia criar uma especialização dela sem esse método.